# jQuery sample application to look for best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Is there a jQuery sample application where I can look for best practices like:

- XMLHttpRequest retries in case of network problems
- XMLHttpRequest login
- XMLHttpRequest element loading indicator
- XMLHttpRequest history handling

?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find 1 application that provides code where all this is done, but it is all stuff that could be handled pretty easily.

> XMLHttpRequest retries in case of network problems

http://www.zeroedandnoughted.com/?p=185

---

A login is actually pretty basic.... Just create a php page that accepts the username/pass and handles the login.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

---

> XMLHttpRequest element loading indicator
>   Do you want to show an animated image while loading?
>   If so, then you want to

1. Show Loading Gif
2. Preform Ajax request
3. Add ajax data return to page
4. Remove/hide loading image

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an application, but 'jQuery: Novice to Ninja' book is free today, it is suppose to go over those kinds of things.

http://sale.sitepoint.com/

I hope I am not breaking any ruse by posting that, I am in no way associated with it, I just came across it a little while ago.